# How I can call the installer.ini arguments in a silent installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I use this code to install in silent mode a program :

```
 private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

            string configfilename = path + "config.ini";
            string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";

            string configtext = File.ReadAllText(configfilename);
            string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
}
 Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet";
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
}
```

But this code made `setup.exe` to run, but doesn't use the installer.ini where I have the `license` number, `outlog` number ...How I can do this, to use the arguments of `installer.ini` for a silent installer of Matlab program ?

Also I tried this :

```
Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\temp\installer.ini";
             process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet";
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It seems that you should provide *installerfilename* and/or *configfilename* as *command line arguments* to the *setup.exe*; see http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-noninteractively-silent-installation.html

Comment: this thing: setup.exe -inputFile C:\temp\installer.txt I don't know how to do

Comment: This may be helpful as well: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/106140-how-do-i-utilize-silent-activation-using-activate-ini

Comment: Already I have this: !insertmacro ExecWaitJob "D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe -if C:\temp\installer.ini" in NSIS, but what I don't know is how to put in c#

Comment: As far as I can see, you want to execute `"D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe -if C:\temp\installer.ini"`; in C# it could be something like `process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe";` and `"process.StartInfo.Arguments = -if C:\temp\installer.ini";`

Comment: I tried but I have 4 errors : "Invalide expression term if" , "Syntax error, '(' expected ... I tried to change the syntax  but I fail ...

Comment: Eh, `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-if C:\temp\installer.ini";` since `Arguments` is a *string*

Comment: I put in my post the code, but doesn't work

Comment: Look, `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet";` totaly *re-writes* previous `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\temp\installer.ini";`. So, *remove*  `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet"` and *edit* `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer.ini";`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/106140-how-do-i-utilize-silent-activation-using-activate-ini

http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-noninteractively-silent-installation.html

the installer wants `-if` key and `installer.ini` file, so the C# syntax will be

```
   // Put IDisposable into using
   using (Process process = new Process()) {
     // The installer itself 
     process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Matlab\NSIS\R2008a\win64\setup.exe";
     // suggested (see links above)  arguments
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-if C:\temp\installer.ini";

     process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
   }
```