# How I can modify the code to have in a text file just a value after equal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the next code :

```
foreach (var te in lin)
{

    if (te.Contains("license=") && te.Contains("license=false" ))
    {

        installertext = installertext.Replace("license=false", "license= " + "true");

    }
    else if (te.Contains("license="))
    {

        installertext = installertext.Replace("license=", "license=" + "true");

    }

    File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
}
```

and in `text file` in row who containt `license=` appear `license=truetrue`.
How I can put the condition to verify if the row is empty or make this code to write just `license=true`? I tried to put a `break;` but if I do this `license=` remain `license=`

Comment: `te.Contains("license=") && te.Contains("license=false" )` isn't is the same as just `te.Contains("license=false" )` ?

Comment: Do you have one entry per line or will you have additional text along with "license=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace

```
  "license=false" => "license=true"
  "license="      => "license=true"
```

Side note: you *don't expect* to ran into `"license=true"`, do you? You can use *Linq*:

```
  var target = lin
    .Select(line => line.Contains("license=") 
      ? line.Contains("license=false") 
          ? line.Replace("license=false", "license=true")
          : line.Replace("license=", "license=true")
      : line);

  File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, target);
```

**Edit**: if you want to replace whateever `"license=sometext"`:

```
 var target = lin
   .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=true"));

 File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, target);
```

Comment: and If I want to replace any, not matter what I have after '=', with license=true, how I can do this ?

Comment: @ben: in case you want to replace `license=SomeText` into `license=true` (e.g. `license=`, `license=true`, `license=false`, `license=bla-bla-bla`) you can use *regular expressions*, see my edit

Comment: As I can see you know a lot of things, It's to mach for you to help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689764/how-i-can-call-the-installer-ini-arguments-in-a-silent-installer ?

Comment: I tried to put this code in my program, but doesn't work. you can help me please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731966/how-i-can-modify-the-code-to-make-work-all-statements?noredirect=1#comment53309508_32731966

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading text file line by line, like with `StreamReader`, then you can check if line is empty or if equals `"license="` whitout true.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Filename"))
{

    while (sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        if(line.Trim().Length != 0 && line.Trim().Equals("license="))
        {
            //Do whatever you need to do
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand much since provided code is less but what i observed is that you are setting license=true everytime. So better do it like this:

```
 if ((te.Contains("license=")) && (te.Contains("license=false" )))
 {
        installertext = installertext.Replace("license=false", "license=true");
 }
 if (te.Contains("license="))
 {
        installertext = installertext.Replace("license=", "license=true");
 }
```