# How I can modify the code to make work all statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the next code :

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string configfilename = path + "config.ini";
    string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";

    string configtext = File.ReadAllText(configfilename);
    string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);

    var link = File.ReadLines(path + "config.ini").ToArray();
    var lin = File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();

    foreach (var txt in link)
    {

        if (txt.Contains("PLP="))
        {
            var PLPPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
            installertext = installertext.Replace("fileInstallationKey=", "fileInstallationKey=" + PLPPath);
        }
        else if (txt.Contains("Output="))
        {
            var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
            installertext = installertext.Replace("outlog=", "outlog=" + outputPath);
        }
        else
        {

            var license = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);

            var lmgr_files = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=false"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, lmgr_files);

            var lmgr_service = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_service=.*", "lmgr_service=false"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, lmgr_service);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
    }
```

But the problem is this code copies the data from `config.ini` in `installer.ini`, from the `PLP row`, `Output` row. And in `installer.ini` the rows :`license`, `lmgr_files`, `lmgr_service` are not completed with data : `yes`, `false`, `false`.
With other words who is after else doesn't work .
How I can modify the code to make all statements execute?

In `installer.ini` I have many things but the most important are :

```
license=false //I want to have license=yes
lmgr_files=   //I want to have lmgr_files= 
lmgr_service=  
fileInstallationKey=0000000  //the number from config.ini
outlog="jhaoif"              //the code from config.ini
```

Comment: remove the else brace for "license, lmgr_files, lmgr_service" and for output remove "else if" use "if:.

Comment: | already tried to remove the else, but still doesn't work

Comment: Your else part is not executing. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that I want to say

Comment: That's what I'm saying remove " else  {" "}" from your code, then it's will work fine.

Comment: Don't work fine what? replace is not working or something else

Comment: not works together ...

Comment: "license, lmgr_files, lmgr_service" this line is not depends on foreach cut and past after the foreach block.

Comment: I tried but the same thing ...

Comment: In "installerfilename" -- license=yes is not replaced, is that your problem?

Comment: yes this is the problem

Comment: is that possible for you to provide some sample config.ini and installer.ini

Comment: var license = Regex.Replace(lin, @"license=.*", "license=yes");           
var lmgr_files = Regex.Replace(lin, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=false"); Try this by removing else.

Comment: I think the problem is here File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);

Comment: I have posted the answer, try and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
string configfilename = path + "config.ini";
string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";

var link = File.ReadLines(path + "config.ini").ToArray();
var lin = File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();
IEnumerable<string> newInstaller = lin;
foreach (var txt in link)
 {

     if (txt.Contains("PLP="))
     {
        var PLPPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
        newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"fileInstallationKey=.*", "fileInstallationKey=" + PLPPath));                   
     }
     if (txt.Contains("Output="))
     {
         var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
         newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"outlog=.*", "outlog=" + outputPath));  
     }
 }
newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes"));
newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=false"));
newInstaller = newInstaller.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_service=.*", "lmgr_service=true"));

string strWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newInstaller.ToArray());

File.WriteAllText(installerfilename,strWrite);
```

Comment: wouuu in the new file all rows are on the same row

Comment: I have updated the code by adding new Environment.NewLine.

Comment: @ben I have updated the code by adding new Environment.NewLine and convert the IEnumerable<string> to Array.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanism to read/write to ini file. There is no need to re-invent the wheel here. Take a look at
[Reading/writing an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)