# How to modify multiple rows in a text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ini

If I put in my code next statements work:

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var lin =File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();
var license = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);
}
```

in `installer.ini` I will have :`license=yes`. 
But if I add another one, , just the second one will be work .

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    var lin =File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();
    var license = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes"));
                File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);
 var lmgr_files = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=true"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, lmgr_files);
    }
```

In `installer.ini` remain `license=no` and will be  `lmgr_files=true` .
How I can make the second code to work, and way doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it in one loop. Something like that:

```
       var lin = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(path,"installer.ini")).ToArray();
       var license = lin.Select(line =>
       {
           line = Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes");
           //you can simply add here more regex replacements
           //line = Regex.Replace(line, @"somethingElse=.*", "somethingElse=yes");

           return Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=true");
       });

       File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);
```

Comment: your answer help me so mach, and the same thing you can help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731966/how-i-can-modify-the-code-to-make-work-all-statements?noredirect=1#comment53309508_32731966the difference is just the fact that I have another statement who help me to copy some data from another file, and I want to make a conection between this

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase you are reading the file *once*, writing it *twice*.

First you are editing the `license` row, writing the edited file. Then you are editing the `lmgr_files` row, *overwriting* your previous edit.

Remove your first call to `File.WriteAllLines()`. In your second `select`, use `license` (i.e. what the first `Select()` returned) instead of `lin` (i.e. the original content of the file).

```
// Use Path.Combine() to combine path parts.
var lin = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(path, "installer.ini")).ToArray();

// Replace the license=... part. License will now hold the edited file.
var license = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"license=.*", "license=yes"));

// No need to write the file here, as it will be overwritten.
//File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, license);

// Select from the edited lines (i.e. "license").
var lmgr_files = license.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_files=.*", "lmgr_files=true"));

// Now it is time to write!
File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, lmgr_files);
```

Optionally, use a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file) for editing INI files.

Comment: Thank you ! and you can help me, please, with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731966/how-i-can-modify-the-code-to-make-work-all-statements?noredirect=1#comment53309508_32731966

Comment: Isn't that the exact same question?

Comment: no, there I have the first part in which I copy some data from another file text

Comment: and here If I want to add another one statement, I tried to put this: var lmgr_service = lmgr_files.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"lmgr_service=.*", "lmgr_service=false"));
            File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, lmgr_service); but doesn't work